# Google drive download whole folder content with google drive viewer (google apps-script)

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, email-attachments, google-drive-api

I have created an google script which go to my mail and fetch attachments and put it into a folder (shared as anyone with link), and share the link to folder with any given email.
But when others open that folder with link it open in google drive viewer(online). Have to open each and every file to download. Is there any way I can let them download whole batch in much more less stressing way?
I have tried out creating a folder (lets say folderchild) inside that folder(folderparent) then put all files in folderchild. But still same problem. Have to open that folderchild and open files in there and download them one by one.
Zipping attachment is not an option for my solution.
Any advices?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you share a map via Google drive and send the link via email your link has an url of following format:
https://drive.google.com/a/FOO/folderview?id=BAR&usp=sharing_eid
where FOO is the domainname of your organization and
BAR is the unique id of the folder (similar to i3AV_u1UsLmTa-dOm22I2XXgioDR8)

Change this url to the following
https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/BAR

Now you can click on the name of the folder and download all files.
Note: this is what works today (Jan. '15) in an GAFE (Google Apps For Education) environment.

Answer (score 7):

They should regress to their own drive, choose the "Shared with Me" option, tick the required folder and use the "More" -> "download" option to download all the content in a zip file

Comment: But what if they don't have any google account? Is there any solution? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

There is OPEN IN DRIVE option in upper right corner, (if you are logged in with your google account). It will put a folder of the same name on your google drive. Then you can right click on the folder and select Download option (zip file will be made and downloaded) :)

Answer (score 1):

When they're viewing the folder in their Google Drive, don't they have the option to select it, click the "More" button and pick "Download"?

If not, that seems like a bug on Drive and you should report it in the Drive forum / issue tracker.

Comment: No I can't see it. All I can see is this with the given link.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B27WaIUHQGy0WFlEYzBSREN1XzA
Any suggestions? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems, by looking at the top right corner on the screenshot, that you're not logged in your Google Docs account. Maybe the download feature is not available for non users. In that case I have no suggestions, maybe you should complain on the Google Docs forum/issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file(s) first, I get that option after I select(ed) the files to download ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on user906489. His URL works, except in the case when using multiple google accounts *and* the url should *not* reference the first account.

In that case just insert `u/USERID/` after `https://drive.google.com/drive/`, so that
`https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/BAR`
becomes
`https://drive.google.com/drive/u/USERID/#folders/BAR`
where, USERID is the number (greater than zero) of your google account.